# Como fazer um request eu um xml via soap em php?

Tags: php, xml

Pessoal estou com problema para enviar um XML para outro servidor TOTVS, preciso fazer em php usando Soap porém estou tendo um erro de argumento invalido porém testando SoapUI como o mesmo XML conseguir encaminhar e no php dá o erro abaixo:

> Error: SoapFault exception: [Sender] WEBSERVICE ERROR : Argument
>   Missing : Required field INMSG not found. in
>   C:\laragon\www\webservice\soapTest.php:164 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\laragon\www\webservice\soapTest.php(164):
>   SoapClient->__soapCall('RECEIVEMESSAGE', Array) #1 {main}

abaixo segue o código php como o xml que estou tentando passar

```
wsdl   = "http://Server/ws/EAISERVICE.apw?WSDL"; 
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(  'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 'trace' => true,  )); 
try {

    $xml = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:tot='http://www.totvs.com/'>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tot:RECEIVEMESSAGE>
         <tot:INMSG><![CDATA[
      '<TOTVSIntegrator>  
    <GlobalProduct>PROTHEUS</GlobalProduct>  
    <GlobalFunctionCode>EAI</GlobalFunctionCode>  
    <GlobalDocumentFunctionCode>STINTP02</GlobalDocumentFunctionCode>  
    <GlobalDocumentFunctionDescription>CADASTRO CLIENTE</GlobalDocumentFunctionDescription>  
    <DocVersion>1.3</DocVersion>  
    <DocDateTime>2019-10-07T14:00:42Z</DocDateTime>  
    <DocIdentifier>5dd6a08b-5dd6-5dd6-5dd6-5dd6a08b4318</DocIdentifier>  
    <DocCompany>09</DocCompany>  
    <DocBranch>0901</DocBranch>  
    <DocName>AURORA TERMINAIS</DocName>  
    <DocFederalID>01777936000196</DocFederalID>  
    <DocType>1</DocType>  
    <Message>  
        <Layouts>  
            <Identifier>STINTP02</Identifier>  
            <Version>1.0</Version>  
            <FunctionCode>U_STINTP02</FunctionCode>  
            <Content>  
                <MATA030 version='1.01' Operation='I'>  
                    <MATA030_SA1 modeltype='FIELDS'>  
                        <A1_XCOD>  
                            <value>XPTO0003</value>  
                        </A1_XCOD>  
                        <A1_PESSOA>  
                            <value>J</value>  
                        </A1_PESSOA>  
                        <A1_NOME>  
                            <value>GS ANUNCIACAO - ME</value>  
                        </A1_NOME>  
                        <A1_NREDUZ>  
                            <value>A.G.S</value>  
                        </A1_NREDUZ>  
                        <A1_TIPO>  
                            <value>F</value>  
                        </A1_TIPO>
                        <A1_END>  
                            <value>RUA 32 QD A43, 15</value>  
                        </A1_END>
                        <A1_EST>  
                            <value>AM</value>  
                        </A1_EST>  
                        <A1_COD_MUN>  
                            <value>02603</value>  
                        </A1_COD_MUN>  
                        <A1_MUN>  
                            <value>MANAUS</value>  
                        </A1_MUN>  
                        <A1_BAIRRO>  
                            <value>PLANALTO</value>  
                        </A1_BAIRRO>  
                        <A1_CEP>  
                            <value>69044210</value>  
                        </A1_CEP>
                        <A1_COMPLEM>  
                            <value>55</value>  
                        </A1_COMPLEM>  
                        <A1_DDD>  
                            <value>92</value>  
                        </A1_DDD>  
                        <A1_TEL>  
                            <value>33031510</value>  
                        </A1_TEL>  
                        <A1_PAIS>  
                            <value>105</value>  
                        </A1_PAIS>  
                        <A1_PAISDES>  
                            <value>BRASIL</value>  
                        </A1_PAISDES>  
                        <A1_CGC>  
                            <value>16604094000148</value>  
                        </A1_CGC>  
                        <A1_INSCR>  
                            <value>ISENTO</value>  
                        </A1_INSCR>  
                        <A1_INSCRM>  
                            <value>22581701</value>  
                        </A1_INSCRM>  
                        <A1_CONTA>  
                            <value>11220001</value>  
                        </A1_CONTA>  
                        <A1_RECISS>  
                            <value>1</value>  
                        </A1_RECISS>  
                        <A1_CODPAIS>  
                            <value>01058</value>  
                        </A1_CODPAIS>  
                        <A1_TPESSOA>  
                            <value>CI</value>  
                        </A1_TPESSOA>  
                        <A1_RECINSS>  
                            <value>N</value>  
                        </A1_RECINSS>
                        <A1_RECCOFI>  
                            <value>N</value>  
                        </A1_RECCOFI>  
                        <A1_RECCSLL>  
                            <value>N</value>  
                        </A1_RECCSLL>  
                        <A1_RECPIS>  
                            <value>N</value>  
                        </A1_RECPIS>  
                        <A1_MSBLQL>  
                            <value>2</value>  
                        </A1_MSBLQL>  
                        <A1_RECIRRF>  
                            <value>2</value>  
                        </A1_RECIRRF>  
                        <A1_XORIEN>  
                            <value>1</value>  
                        </A1_XORIEN>  
                        <A1_XFORMPG>  
                            <value>1</value>  
                        </A1_XFORMPG>
                        <A1_LOJA>  
                            <value>TESTE</value>  
                        </A1_LOJA_>
                        <A1_RISCO>  
                            <value>A</value>  
                        </A1_RISCO>
                        <A1_EMAIL>  
                            <value>alexsandro@agsrepresentacoes.net.br</value>  
                        </A1_EMAIL>  
                        <A1_XMAILCB>  
                            <value>email@email.com.br;email2</value>  
                        </A1_XMAILCB>
                        <A1_ENDCOB>  
                            <value>RUA ABC, 275</value>  
                        </A1_ENDCOB>
                        <A1_BAIRROC>  
                            <value>BAIRRO COBRANCA</value>  
                        </A1_BAIRROC>  
                        <A1_CEPC>  
                            <value>66610190</value>  
                        </A1_CEPC>  
                        <A1_MUNC>  
                            <value>BELEM</value>  
                        </A1_MUNC>  
                        <A1_ESTC>  
                            <value>PA</value>  
                        </A1_ESTC>  
                    </MATA030_SA1>  
                </MATA030>  
            </Content>  
        </Layouts>  
    </Message>  
</TOTVSIntegrator>']]></tot:INMSG>
      </tot:RECEIVEMESSAGE>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";

    $args = array(new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML));    
    $res  = $client->__soapCall('RECEIVEMESSAGE', $args);
    //return $res;
} 
catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo "Error: {$e}";
}

echo "<hr>Last Request";
echo "<pre>", htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()), "</pre>";

echo "<hr>Last Response";
echo "<pre>", htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse()), "</pre>";
```

alguém poderia me ajudar com isso se tem alguma coisa errada no código, pois não tenho muita familiaridade com Soap.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).